# sqldatabase variable declaration from a listbox in Vb.net 2010

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-2010, listboxitem

I'm trying to save the selected Item from the listbox to the database but when i choose the item from the listbox I get a Runtime error that the variable(RomID) is not declared. Here's the code. What am I missing?!

```
    If (con.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
        con.Open()
    End If


    Dim Name As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@Name", TxtName.Text)
    Dim Pass As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@PassportNum", TxtPassNum.Text)
    Dim Mobile As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@PhoneNUm", TxtMobile.Text)
    Dim RomID As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@ID", Integer.Parse(ListBox1.SelectedItem))
    Dim ChckIn As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@CheckIndate", DateTime.Now.Date)
    Dim Email As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@Email", TxtEmail.Text)

    Cmd.Parameters.Add(Name)
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(Pass)
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(Mobile)
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(RomID)
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(ChckIn)
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(Email)
    Cmd.CommandText = "Update Rooms set Status ='Booked' where ID = @RomID"
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Cmd.CommandText = "insert into Reservation(RoomID,GuestName,PassportNum,PhoneNUm,CHeckIndate,Email) VALUES(@RomID,@Name,@Pass,@Mobile,@ChckIn,@Email)"
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Reservation Was Successful")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not declared in the same way  can you try this:

remove:

```
Dim RomID As SqlParameter =
  New SqlParameter("@ID", Integer.Parse(ListBox1.SelectedItem))
```

try something like this :

```
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
command.Parameters("@ID").Value = Integer.Parse(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
```

Comment: in VB 2010 i can't have "command.parameters." everytime i try to type that i end up having an error!

Comment: Try to delcare it like this:  Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(commandText, connection)  This is from a MSDN example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
Dim RomID As SqlParameter =
  New SqlParameter("@ID", Integer.Parse(ListBox1.SelectedItem))
```

I think you meant this:

```
Dim RomID As SqlParameter =
  New SqlParameter("@RomID", Integer.Parse(ListBox1.SelectedItem))
```

Comment: I have tried changing that but I end up facing the same error either way!